# How to use CREATE/DROP table inside IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am migrating data from a series of old data tables to new tables. In this process I came upon some issues.

I need to create a table, copy some data from old table to new one then drop old table. To achieve this, I need to write a script that does not show errors even if you run it on a migrated database, meaning even if the old tables are not there I should not see errors and simply skip the process.

Following is what I came up with up to now:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID('Old_Table'))
    GOTO Migrated_Before

  -- Drop OldTable Indexes, PK's and FK's;
  -- CREATE newTable ....;
  -- Add Indexes, PK's, Fk's;
  -- INSERT INTO NewTable(someFields) FROM OldTable.Fields, OtherTable.Fields ...;
  -- DROP OldTable;

Migrated_Before:
```

Here is the issue, Drop and Create need GO to commit changes before continue to next stage otherwise, next command will fail, however putting GO between GOTO and Label will make label undefined for GOTO.

How can I force each process to run before continue to next one without writing IF multiple times?

Solution: I leave the solution here as reference for others.
I added begin transaction before every statement that need to happen before proceeding to next statement, for example, create table or drop FK's. and also replaced goto and label with begin end (my first solution)

Comment: Before anything else, I'd reconsider your use of `GOTO`. It is, after all, *considered harmful* - http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to avoid IF?  I frequently work on schema change scripts that need to be idempotent, where incremental changes need to be committed / separated with GO, and IF seems to work better for me than GOTO.

Comment: @Yuck, nice point but I can't use begin end either still each line should run before I can do next and `GO` won't work inside `begin`,`end`

Comment: using multiple if in my code makes it unreadable when I have multiple indexes and FK's on table to delete and do same for over 10 tables

Comment: Looks like trying to preserve the indexes of the OldTable in the NewTable.  Then, drop OldTable.  Just rename and you're done.

Comment: Heck, if you want to get fancy, you can have table of "OldTableName, NewTableName" pairs and use dynamic sql to iterate through and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `begin transaction`, `commit` instead of `go`

Comment: commit requires a corresponding transaction.  no transaction is opened here.

Comment: Sam, obviously that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the CREATE, DROP and following 3 commands in a separate stored procedure and call that procedure after GOTO. This SP will contan the required GO statement. This may keep the scope of Label as it is.

Comment: Good Idea, it pointed me to good direction, I can use sp_execute to run the commands. although it makes my code a little messy

Answer (score 1):

I can run this code below without any "GO"

```
if object_id('abc') is not null
    drop table abc
create table abc (asdf varchar(10))

if object_id('abc') is not null
    drop table abc
create table abc (asdf varchar(10))

if object_id('abc') is not null
    drop table abc
create table abc (asdf varchar(10))
```

Also, you can just check for object_id() of null instead of querying the sys.objects table.

Comment: Sam, your answer is correct and you still need go, however you need to repeat the if multiple times that makes your SQL hard to read, specially when you are doing same thing for 25 tables and each have 3~8 indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you need to repeat the if multiple times"? It's repeated just to show you that "GO" is not needed.

Comment: You should not be using "GOTO" to handle this.  Maybe you should look into wrapping this into a stored procedure and running it per table.

Also, why do you need to drop and re-create tables?  Will the table definition change each time?  Or can you get away by just purging the data and recreating the indexes? (truncate).  What you trying to do a little confusing... I think there's definitely a more "readable" solution.  Please share with us what exactly you're doing and why and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: After more careful inspection of what you're trying to do.  You're looking for some sort of an archiving solution.  It's probably better to just rename the table and be done with it.  exec sp_rename.

Comment: Sam, if you are using MS-SQL Server, you need to use go to apply your changes. if does not do the job of go it is only the condition.

Comment: Couldn't you separate the script out into logical sections with "GO"?  Ie. if you have 25 tables you're working with, couldn't you use GO to group each table up?  

if table1 exists do something go
if table2 exists do something go
...

Imho, having unnecessary goto and begin transactions will make the code messy. Especially if you do not need to do it in a transaction.  Not to mention the overhead of using a transaction.